# How to set a Cron job in Every one hour from 9:00 am to 6:00 pm ( Monday to Friday )

Tags: cron, cron-task

**How to set a Cron job in Every one hour from 9:00 am to 6:00 pm ( Monday to Friday)**

I am using Hostgator cron job to send mail every one hour, Now I want it from Monday to Friday. below is the link to screen shot.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0123cmfxe1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
0 9-18 * * 1-5 /path_to_script
```

EDIT:

In the format of the boxes it would be

```
0
9-18
*
*
1-5
```

Comment: is there any way to give particular time for one day? Some thing like Friday 9-13:00

Comment: As well as this or instead of this?

Comment: You would need to set up a separate cron job to do that

Comment: That means instead of 1-5 I would write 1-4 and a separate cron task only for friday.?

Comment: @Syam as this is now a new question on an old post, you need to make a new question mate

Comment: Here is the link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031450/how-to-set-a-cron-job-in-every-two-hour-from-10-19**