# How to set a Cron job in Every two hour from 10-19

Tags: cron, cron-task

I had a question before 1 month regarding this. that was the interval of 1 hour and i got exact answer. below is the link to the old question

[How to set a Cron job in Every one hour from 9:00 am to 6:00 pm ( Monday to Friday )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424102/how-to-set-a-cron-job-in-every-one-hour-from-900-am-to-600-pm-monday-to-frid/25424200?noredirect=1#comment40765947_25424200)

Thank you **Stack Over Flow** and the contributor **Andy Holmes**

Now I got a new requirement on Cron expression, the same way i need it in every 2 hour.

I have tried

> 0 9/2-18/2 * * 1-5

and

> 0 (9-18)/2 * * 1-5

But that doesn't help, Please help me

Comment: Doesn't the man page show an example of this? It does on my Mac.

Comment: what does this have to do with programming? it seems like [unix.se] would be a much better fit for this question.

Comment: @strugee As I am a beginner I stuck with this,this project has many reporting task, Please do not try demotivate any one. I got one answer right Even if it doesn't make me scenes, thank you Barmar

Comment: What more do you need? I showed how to do it both ways in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
0 10-18/2 * * 1-5
```

You specify the hour range `9-18` and then `/2` to mean step by `2` hours. The man page explains this pretty clearly:

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with `/<number>` specifies skips of the number's value through the range.  For example, `0-23/2` can be used in the hours field to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`).  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say "every two hours", just use `*/2`.

If your interface doesn't allow this shorthand, you have to list them out by hand:

```
0 10,12,14,16,18 * * 1-5
```

Comment: It is giving me error. Here is the link for reference **http://awesomescreenshot.com/0483jqr888**

Comment: What happens if you edit the crontab by hand, rather than using cPanel?

Comment: As this is hostgator account I don't have permission to do that or I haven't see that option yet.

Comment: If cPanel doesn't support the shorthand, you just list the hours.